# FilenotFoundError with Pyinstaller : Some Modules are not included in application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a tkinter application with PyInstaller but I can't seem to resolve a missing module issue.

Here is (roughly) my file architecture :

```
app
 ┣ summar-env
 ┃ ┣ lib
 ┃ ┃ ┣ python3.9
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ site-packages
 ┣ my_app.py
 ┣ abstractive_summarization_transformers.py
 ┣ extractive_summarization_textrank.py
 ┣ extractive_summarization_word_frequency.py
 ┗ utils.py
```

I am working in a virtual environment `summar-env` in which everything works. `my_app.py` imports the modules in the same directory.

So I tried building the app directly with `PyInstaller my_app.py` in `onedir` mode. I got :
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: path/to/app/dist/evaluation_app/icecream/__version__.py'`
Even when adding the module with `hidden-import=icecream"`

So eventually I tried adding the missing modules directly to the spec file `myhiddenimports=["icecream", "fr_core_news_sm"]` as well as the path to the directory containing the modules in the environment `pathex=['path/to/app/summar-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages']`, before building directly from the spec file but to no avail.

I mention this module but I expect many other ones to be missing based on the list in the warn file in build directory (so I will need a way to add all those missing files)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/18072035) help you?

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. Simtimes you need to incloude non python files. Some things require datatables or images. Could that be the case?

Comment: I forgot to add that I am using onedir mode for debugging. But it does not work either.